# TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode' - react typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I tried to console map function then I am getting this error - **TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'**.

React JS code is below

```
const ReduxComp: React.FC = () => {
const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();
const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState<{}[] | []>([]);
const { products, loading, error } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.products);

useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
},[]);

useEffect(()=>{
    setProductsData(products);
},[products]);

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Redux Comp</h2>
        {
            productsData.length > 0 &&  productsData.map<any>((d:any,index:number) => (<div key={index}>
                { console.log('d - ', d) } // Here I am getting error
            </div>))
        }
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should not be mixing `console.log` calls inside of JSX.

The reason for the error is that `console.log` returns `undefined`. A valid React node is either JSX, a string, or null. You probably want `null`.

Easiest solution is to coalesce it to a `null`:

```
console.log('d - ', d) ?? null
```